# how do i split an string every [" "] in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello so I'm wondering if I have a string
like this

```
var string = '"In Another World" "Magic Books"'
```

how can I make an array every that contains every name in the [""] ??

the result that I want :

an array named 'Array' that contains every name from the string

an error that appears if the ["] has no second ["]

for an example :

```
var string = '"example'
```

it will return an error

and if there is no [""] it will make an array that contain string value

Comment: This could push you in the right direction: `'"In Another World" "Magic Books"'.match(/"(.*?)"/g)`

Comment: aaa okay so.. is that will return an array ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
string = '"In Another World" "Magic Books"';
const tempArr = string.split('"');
const filteredArr = tempArr.filter(function (el) {
  return el != null;
}); 
console.log(filteredArr)
```

You should not use `"` this a marker or split point as both `'` and `"` represents string so its better to use any other symbols or character like `*` or `:` .